# Can we retrieve messages from amazon connect platform through sdk or any other means?

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-connect

I'm building a chatbot on my end and want to maintain a customer-agent chat flow where customer will be on my platform and agent will be on the amazon connect platform. Thus, I would like to retrieve messages from amazon connect platform as well. I have checked the docs and some sdks but nothing seems to help.

I have used GetTranscript sdk, it is providing me a transcript of the session, including details about any attachments, but there is no triggering event where I can get the latest messages not all the messages and also automatically not where I need to call this sdk in order to retrieve the messages. I have also looked for webhooks, checked web sockets, explored its lambda function but nothing seems to be helpful.

Please let me know if there is any further details required from my end.

Comment: add more details like what you have tried so far!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for the [Participant API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect-participant/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html).
There is JS SDK that wraps the API, try the [onMessage](https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-chatjs#chatsessiononmessage) event.